# What is the name of this effect in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, animation, adobe, effects

how to create an intro animation just like this:

? What is the name of the effect (time around 00:00:02 until 00:00:05)? I am trying to search it over Youtube but doesn't find something that I want.

The main effect that I am looking for is the text forming from a bubble and the bubble bouncing over the text. Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify a time? That's a five and a half minute video.

Comment: @stib Hi Stib, revised the description

Comment: The name of the effect is "animation". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animation

Comment: You can search "After Effects morphing" and you will find some tutorials which you will help to recreate intro like in this video.
It's not a standart (by default) effect in After Effects. It's an animation created from scratch, probably in After Effects.

Shape Animation

Answer (score -1):

You can search "After Effects morphing" and you will find some tutorials which you will help to recreate intro like in this video. It's not a standard (by default) effect in After Effects. It's an animation created from scratch, probably in After Effects. It's a Shape Animation, shape morphing, mask morphing, liquid animation.

Comment: That's not morphing.  It's just animation.  There's about 10 circles moving around very quickly, with motion blur.  The letters squash and stretch independently, the background inverts its color independently, and it all happens quickly, and coherently.  It's a good animation, but there aren't plugins to do it.  Morphing maps one shape to another, and then creates incremental versions by both moving pixels spatially and cross-dissolving the pixel color values.  There are plugins to do morphing, and they won't help here, because that's different.  Morphing = tweening + dissolve.